# Get xprop class of gnome-screenshot

Tags: window-manager, gnome-screenshot, compton, xprop

I'm using a window manager and compositor in Ubuntu. I have blur enabled for transparent windows, which means that when I take a screenshot with gnome-screenshot, the content I'm trying to take a picture of is blurred. With xprop, or some other tool, how do I identify the class of the screenshot window so that I can add it to my blur-exclude rule in my compositor config?

When I start xprop, then take a screenshot and click on the screenshot window, I'm prompted with the following, which doesn't give me any information about the class of the window:

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS

X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x4001a3
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

Comment: `gnome-screenshot` intercepts the mouseclick event, does its trick, and exits before `xprop` sees the mouseclick event. Read `man xprop` AND all the `man` pages mentioned in the "`SEE ALSO`" section. Use one of the information dumpers that runs unconditionally (without a mouseclick), preface it with `sleep 25; `, take up to 20 seconds to start `gnome-screenshot`, but don't  mouseclick, wait 15 seconds, then click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `xprop WM_CLASS` will not work as you expect. Consult `man xprop` to learn how the program works. To obtain the WM_CLASS and filter out any other information, use

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```